# What to do if the article is rejected due to misunderstanding

Tags: publications, journals, paper-submission, rejection, indexing

I had my paper returned from several journals saying that it does not match their subjects areas, no reviewer agreed to review it etc. even though I had checked properly regarding the subject scope of the journals before submitting. They were all indexed journals in Web of Science, so perhaps they felt that the impact of my article was not enough.

But from my side, I had worked to obtain the results mentioned in the article and am very grateful if it gets accepted by a journal with good indexing, like that from Web of science (like Science citation index expanded, emerging sources citation index etc.) or SCOPUS indexed journals. In our university those two are the most accepted indexing criteria. So that's why I tried such a journal.

In the journal where I had submitted before the last submission, I felt that the reviewer has not understood my expression of the result clearly so when it got rejected, I rewrote it with more explanations and submitted again.

Then, it got rejected again, but fortunately they have sent me a complete reviewer report (in earlier cases I didn't get such a report). There, according to the comments, I can clearly see that the reviewer has misunderstood some of the elements I mention and hence he gets it as a weak result. With regards to this, I have explained the elements to be considered very clearly too, I don't know what else can be done to make it clear.

Moreover, I have waited for the response of several journals now, and with regards to the time durations I am concerned with getting the publication for some of my important works. So, what can I do now?

Are there reliable author services which will help me to get the paper published in a good journal, in a short time period?

Or should I try a journal which is not indexed? If that is the case, I am at the disadvantage because other people will not value my hard work right?

Is there anything I can do, to get it published while maintaining its quality? I'm very glad if anyone can advise me. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: There are many questions in here, many of which are addressed in other questions on this site.  I believe that the primary question, about being misunderstood is addressed by the question that I linked.  If you want to ask other portions of this question, I would suggest asking them one at a time as separate questions.

Comment: Did you present your work at conferences? what was the reception? Try to publish on new journals from reputable publishers, if they do not yet have an impact factor, they may be more open to publish weak results, while at the same time "giving you" (in the future) an impact factor for your papers.

Comment: Thank you @jakebeal

Comment: And @EarlGrey I haven't presented it at a conference. My supervisor wasn't very happy with that. He wanted to go for indexed journal publication only and devote my remaining time on studying

Comment: My subject areas are related to Mathematics and Computer science. Can you advise what type of publishers I must check @EarlGrey?

Comment: something like this:
https://www.frontiersin.org/journals/applied-mathematics-and-statistics ?
check their list of jounrals
https://www.frontiersin.org/about/impact?utm_source=fweb&utm_medium=fjour&utm_campaign=impact-2020-jour-hp-top

Comment: I have heard that there are author services (freelance/from publishers). But I'm afraid to submit my work to a completely unknown person. Furthermore, author services from reputed publishers like elsevier are costly according to my current situation which is a problem. If there is any service you can recommend please let me know @jakebeal and EarlGrey

Comment: Thanks a lot @EarlGrey I had checked it earlier too but gave up because of the publication cost (I'm having some problems, hence can afford around 400 USD like price). They have mentioned about waivers too, but there I don't understand whether only the countries involved in a Research4Life programme can apply for it OR any country listed under Research4Life categorization can apply for it? If you know this exaclty please let me know. And also of any other journals with lower impact than the above..?

Comment: " I felt that the reviewer has not understood my expression of the result clearly so when it got rejected" -- there is your problem. If a reader cannot understand what the key point of the paper is, then you've done something wrong as an author.

Comment: Hmm, yes @WolfgangBangerth there was a problem, that it was a very basic computation that I have expressed. Something like, for a function value f(t), the reviewer has thought I'm using t rather than f(t), something like that. Anyhow, I had re-written before submitting again with more explanations and examples as possible. At the moment I'm very nervous now I can't understand ow to explain it further if they misunderstand it like that.

Comment: In the journal before the last I actually emailed the editor with a document including a separate set of examples illustrating my point, he agreed that it seems promising but still didn't change the decision since they wanted to consider articles with even higher quality..He mentioned that he can accept only a few more papers now, so I'd better try another journal more related to technical stuff like presented in mine. But I thought a journal more related to maths, since the mathematical computation should

Comment: be understood clearly for them to be able to accept my paper and that's why I submitted there. No hard feelings though, I only feel as if I need some help and guidance to continue from here

Comment: Find someone who can give you friendly feedback on the paper, rather than go through the peer review process at a journal. Then have a conversation with that person, trying to understand what they think. Reviewers can't provide you with that information.

Comment: Yes, @WolfgangBangerth I'd be much grateful if I can have that. But I'm lacking in that, most of my friends are people who had done bio science related subjects, some others have gone abroad, and not knowledgeable in my subject area... that's why I asked about author services too, so that I can have some exact suggestions..